# What is going on in this code (Python 2.7)?

Tags: python

```
import math
def is_prime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0 and n > 2: 
        return False
    return all(n % i for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2))
```

I received an assignment where I had to find the sum of all prime numbers up to 2 million and the code I wrote originally took way too long to run so the teacher gave me this algorithm to check if the number is prime. However, I don't quite seem to get what's going on in the return all statement and what it has to do with prime numbers

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi, as OP's reputation suggests, he is quite new in this site. He should not deserve this type of critism. Never laugh at people who are struggling, he didn't commit a crime. Try to help him or ignore. Your first comment is more worse than the question itself.

Comment: Your teacher gave you a clever solution which uses [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)  and the Python idea of truth. Try to calculate the formular using some `n`s. Start from the inside ('math.sqrt(n)`)  and write down each step. You will see a pattern for primes and non-primes.

Comment: @user7229209, Welcome to Stack Overflow, SO is more of a question-answer based site. What you are seeking is kind of explanation of a code snippet, which is beyond the scope of this site. I suggest you to do some google search to understand what is going one. The longer you struggle, it will help you that much later.

Comment: This is exactly what's happening in your code. Read here: http://wiki.planetmath.org/howtofindwhetheragivennumberisprimeornot

Answer (score 2):

Since I was not nice to you. Let me just make a little extra effort and explain it you.

First read this:
http://wiki.planetmath.org/howtofindwhetheragivennumberisprimeornot

---

```
import math
def is_prime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0 and n > 2: 
        return False
    return all(n % i for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2))
```

Let's see whats happening here.

**Step1.** `if n % 2 == 0 and n > 2`
Check if the number is divisible by 2 and also greater than 2. If these condition fail then the number is not prime. Don't proceed any further and return false.

**Step2a.** `int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1`
Calculate the square root of the number (it might be float so we convert it into int) and then add 1 to it.

**Step2b.** `range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2)`
Create a list starting from 3 to the value calculated in step2a with a step size of 2. So basically it will get all the odd numbers from 3 to step2a value. Why just odd? Because evens are not prime!

**Step2c.** `(n % i for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2)`
In this step we are iterating over the list created in 2b and dividing n by all of those numbers (by dividing here i mean taking modulus) and we are storing the results in an iterator object.

**Step2d.** `all()`
If n was divisible by any number of list from 2b, then a 0 will be stored on `n % i`. And we know that a prime number is not divisible by any number other than 1 and itself. If we get a `0` then we are done, it's not a prime number.
all() will return true only if all the values are non zero.
Eg. 
`print all([1,2,3,4,5])-->True`
`print all([0,1,2,3,4])-->False`

I hope, now it's clear to you.